# c++ socket sending data after disconnection

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing a socket code with C++ and socket.h library and my server and clients are stream socket with TCP protocol.
I've got a class User that shows the clients connected.

```
class User
{
 private:
    int sockfd;
    int n;
    thread *Thread;
 public:
    User(int sockfd);
    void Get_Message();
    void Join();  
    ~User();
};
User::User(int sockfd)
{
    this->sockfd=sockfd;
    Thread=new thread(&User::Get_Message,this);
}
void User::Get_Message()
{
    while (1)
    {
        readmessage(sockfd);
    }
}
void readmessage(int sock)
{
    int n=0;
    char buffer[256];
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    n = read(sock, buffer, 255);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR reading from socket ");
    }
    cout<<"the message\t"<<buffer<<endl;
}
```

now this code works and several clients can join my server and send message;

However when one of those clients disconnects from the server, it keeps printing `"the message:"` and I don't know why and how to stop it...
I'll be grateful if anybody helps me with the why and how to fix it.

Comment: How can you not know why? You have an infinite loop, `while (1) readmessage(sockfd);` Of course your code is going to keep printing `"the message:"`. The solution is to make `readmessage` return a status and exit the loop when the status indicates the connection was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Get_Message()` while loop, you might need to check if the `sockfd` is valid , hence `sockfd !=0` before reading the message.

Comment: Check it how? and close it why?

Comment: Repeated open and close handshakes are also wasted resources. You need to strike a balance. Most protocols don't use a connection for just one message.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't checking for `read()` (or `recv()`) returning zero, which is the normal case for a disconnected peer.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` or `write` function return zero while the other peer disconnected, and the `buffer` is `null`, so you should deal with this case.

```
void readmessage(int sock)
{
    int n=0;
    char buffer[256];
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    n = read(sock, buffer, 255);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR reading from socket ");
    }
    else if (n == 0)
    {
        cout << sock <<" client disconnected" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"the message\t"<<buffer<<endl;
    }
}
```